# Playframework:activator command not found in mac

Tags: macos, playframework, path, typesafe-activator

I have set up my activator path in mac, but when i want to create a project it said command not found.please help.Here is my path.

> /Documents/activator-1.3.10-minimal/bin:usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin

and here is the error

> mac-score:activator-1.3.10-minimal mac-score$  activator new first-app play-java
>   -bash: activator: command not found

Comment: Check that it has the executable bit set: `chmod +x /Documents/activator-1.3.10-minimal/bin/activator`

Comment: problem solved, thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you are using Homebrew you can do:

```
brew install typesafe-activator
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if correct permissions are given to activator dir

```
chmod -R +rwx activator-dir
```

You can install activator using `Homebrew` to get rid of this hassle

```
brew install activator
```